# nativescript |layouts create ui for ngFor loop

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-angular

,
im try to create an view and having troubles.
im trying to create a row of Images with ngFor , so i dont know the exec number of images that will apper on the screen but in need it to look like that ,
in case of 3 photos it will be in one line but when the fourth Image will added it will go down to a new line[image]

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that problem can be resolve with warpLayout

[WrapLayout](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/layouts/wrap-layout)